# Compute Lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

I have the following easy ODE $$y''=y'+x$$ I am required to compute the Lipschitz constant of the r.h.s. which is (after reducing to first order):$$f([y,y'],x)=[y',y'+x]^t$$

I thought I could just compute the Jacobian, which is

$$J_f = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and since $||J_f||_{\inf}=1$ I'd say that the Lipschitz constant $L =1$. Is this the right way?